# SQLAlchemy: avoid query filter if searched value is None

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is there a one-liner to handle the following scenario:

```
def queryByAttr(attr1,attr2=None):
  if attr2 is None:
    session.query(Foo).filter(Foo.attr1==attr1)
  else:
    session.query(Foo).filter(Foo.attr1==attr1).filter(Foo.attr2==attr2)
```

Answer (score 8):

There is a more readable *multi-liner* using chaining:

```
def queryByAttr(attr1, attr2=None):
    q = session.query(Foo).filter(Foo.attr1 == attr1)
    if attr2 is not None:
        q = q.filter(Foo.attr2 == attr2)
    return q
```

and you can make it a (rather long) *one-liner* as well:

```
def queryByAttr(attr1, attr2=None):
    return (session.query(Foo).filter(Foo.attr1 == attr1)) if attr2 is None else (session.query(Foo).filter(Foo.attr1 == attr1).filter(Foo.attr2 == attr2))
```

*All this assuming you never need a query to return those `Foo`s which have `attr2` value `NULL`.*

Answer (score 0):

Can also use.

```
def queryByAttr(attr1, attr2=None):
    return (session.query(Foo).filter((*[Foo.attr1==attr1, Foo.attr2==attr2] if attr2 else *[Foo.attr1==attr1])))
```