# SQLAlchemy ORM / Python: one-liner to include query filter only if searched value is not None (inline 'if')

Tags: python, if-statement, methods, sqlalchemy, inline

Can I implement in Python an inline `if` at the method level?

Let's take this (simplified) situation:

```
# DB-level 'or'
db.session.query(TableClass).filter(or_(TableClass.column_1 == value_1,
                                        TableClass.column_2 == value_2)).first()

# basic Python-level 'if'
if value_1:
    db.session.query...value_1
if value_2:
    db.session.query...value_2
```

Instead of querying DB or adding additional `if` statements as per above, **is it possible to achieve the same inline** with something like:

```
# desired inline Python 'if' at method level
db.session.query(TableClass).filter({
           if value_1 TableClass.column_1 == value_1 \
           else if value_2 TableClass.column_2 == value_2 else None
    }).first()

# ^-- or something similar at method level
```

Alternatively, have a part of the SQLAlchemy filter be active only when the underlying value exists.

The main motivation here is DRY and avoiding DB search of `None` values.

Tried inline combination of [starred expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) with `if` statement as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41369315/11750716):

```
session.query(Foo).filter((*[Foo.attr1==attr1, Foo.attr2==attr2] if attr2 else *[Foo.attr1==attr1]))
```

but I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` at `if`.

**UPDATE**

For now I went with [this style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34838387/11750716) of defining conditions as separate variables that can be appended together:

```
query = session.query(Table)

conditions = []
if abc:
    conditions.append(Table.field1 == foo)
if def:
    conditions.append(Table.field2 == bar)

query = query.filter(or_(*conditions))
```

Though I appreciate Pierre V's answer below fixing syntax for the starred expression and for the `or_(TableClass.column_1 == value_1, true() if value_1 is None else false())` suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get rid of the syntax error by moving the parentheses:

```py
session.query(Foo).filter(*([Foo.attr1==attr1, Foo.attr2==attr2] if attr2 else [Foo.attr1==attr1]))
```

Otherwise, you might achieve the desired result with [`true()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.true) and [`false()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.false) Sqlalchemy expressions.

Something like:

```py
db.session.query(TableClass).filter(
    or_(TableClass.column_1 == value_1, true() if value_1 is None else false()),
    or_(TableClass.column_2 == value_2, true() if value_2 is None else false())
).first()
```

But imho it feels a lot clunkier than

```py
query = db.session.query(TableClass)
if value_1:
    query = query.filter(TableClass.column_1 == value_1)
if value_2:
    query = query.filter(TableClass.column_2 == value_2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Is `or_(TableClass.column_2 == value_2, true() if value_2 is None else false())` inherent to SQLAlchemy's `or_` function or is it a Python notation?

Comment: I'd say it's a SQLAlchemy thing, as `or_()`, `true()` and `false()` are SQLAlchemy functions